# How to load the "|" character (vertical bar) using vertica copy command

Tags: vertica

I'm trying to load a csv that contains the character "|" without success
can i escape it or use other techinieue?
can you help?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using '|' as your delimiter and some fields also contain '|', you can escape them as '\|'.  (Or with some other character, if you've changed your escape character.  But by default, '\'.)

If you have a lot of these, it might be easier to change your delimiter character.  It doesn't have to be '|'.  For example, you can do this:

```
=> COPY t1 FROM '/data/*.csv' DELIMITER '+';
```

You can use any ASCII value in the range E'\000' to E'\177', inclusive. See the [documentation for COPY parameters](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/Parameters.htm).